# Forms with action=""

Tags: html, forms

I just found out (the hard way), that when you have a HTML form with `action=""`, Webkit browsers treat it differently to Firefox and Internet Explorer.

In FF and IE, these two form tags are equivalent:

```
<form method="post" action="">

<form method="post">
```

They will both submit the form back to the same page. Safari and Chrome however will send that first form to the default page (index.php, or whatever) - the second form works the same as FF/IE.

I've quickly hacked my code so that anywhere where it would normally print an empty action, it doesn't add an action attribute at all.

This seems very messy and not the best way to be doing things. Can anyone suggest a better method? Also, can anyone enlighten me about why Webkit would do such a thing?

Comment: This has/was apparently filed as a bug against webkit [here](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=7763)

Answer (score 28):

I usually use

```
<form method='POST' action='?'>
```

This means the current URL but with no parameters.

Comment: I do this, except I conform to XHTML by using doublequotes.  =]

Comment: You can use single quotes and still have valid XHTML; you don't have to use double quotes.

Comment: Oh, my bad.  I must be misunderstanding the standards than.  Anyway, I prefer doublequotes.

Comment: Actually, I thought it was the other way around. No matter.

Answer (score 14):

The [`action` attribute is required](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#adef-action) but you can specify an empty URI reference that referes to the current URI:

```
<form method="POST" action="">
```

---

**Edit**    Ok, this actually is a filed bug of WebKit 528+ (see [Bug 19884](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=19884)) when an empty URI is used with a specified base URI using the `BASE` element. In that case WebKit takes the base URI instead of resolving the empty URI from the base URI.

But this is [correct behavior according to RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-5.1):

> **5.1.  Establishing a Base URI**
>
> The term "relative" implies that a "base URI" exists against which
> the relative reference is applied. […]
>
> The base URI of a reference can be established in one of four ways,
> discussed below in order of precedence.  The order of precedence can
> be thought of in terms of layers, where the innermost defined base
> URI has the highest precedence.  This can be visualized graphically
> as follows:
>
> ```
>   .----------------------------------------------------------.
>   |  .----------------------------------------------------.  |
>   |  |  .----------------------------------------------.  |  |
>   |  |  |  .----------------------------------------.  |  |  |
>   |  |  |  |  .----------------------------------.  |  |  |  |
>   |  |  |  |  |       <relative-reference>       |  |  |  |  |
>   |  |  |  |  `----------------------------------'  |  |  |  |
>   |  |  |  | (5.1.1) Base URI embedded in content   |  |  |  |
>   |  |  |  `----------------------------------------'  |  |  |
>   |  |  | (5.1.2) Base URI of the encapsulating entity |  |  |
>   |  |  |         (message, representation, or none)   |  |  |
>   |  |  `----------------------------------------------'  |  |
>   |  | (5.1.3) URI used to retrieve the entity            |  |
>   |  `----------------------------------------------------'  |
>   | (5.1.4) Default Base URI (application-dependent)         |
>   `----------------------------------------------------------'
> ```

In this case the `BASE` element with `href` attribute is a *base URI embedded in content*. And *base URI embedded in content* has a higher precedence than *URI used to retrieve the entity*. So WebKit’s behavior is actually the expected behavior according to RFC 3986.

But [in HTML 5 this behavior of an empty URI in `form`’s `action`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/association-of-controls-and-forms.html#form-submission-algorithm) (still a draft) differs from RFC 3986:

> If *action* is the empty string, let *action* be the [document's address](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-document-s-address).

> > Note: This step is a [willful violation](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/introduction.html#willful-violation) of RFC 3986, which would require base URL processing here. This violation is motivated by a desire for compatibility with legacy content. [[RFC3986]](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/references.html#refsRFC3986)

Frankly, an HTML comment after this note in the source code reads:

> ```
> <!-- Don't ask me why. But that's what IE does. It even treats
> action="" differently from action=" " or action="#" (the latter
> two resolve to the base URL, the first one resolves to the doc
> URL). And other browsers concur. It is even required, see e.g.
>   http://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=7763
>   https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=297761
> -->
> ```

So this is rather a bug originated from Internet Explorer that became a de-facto standard.

Comment: ...except that doesn't work in Webkit browsers, as mentioned in the OP.

Comment: The second example is not valid HTML either.

Comment: well no, but it actually works, which is slightly more important.

Comment: This just bit my enterprise when upgrading from FF 52.9 to 61.0.
I narrowed this down as the cause, but did not look up the HTML or RFC standards. Thanks for the background information, and for confirming my findings.

Answer (score 6):

The best way in my opinion would be not to omit the action attribute (which would not validate) but to specify the actual action for the form. Is there a reason you are not specifying the action?

Comment: it's a generic form which is on many pages, some of which could have a series of GET parameters. I've found it much easier to do action="" than to recreate the URL and encode it properly.

Comment: I actually have a helper that parses the url parameters and recreates it accordingly, which I use in most of my projects. Are you using a router pattern? it really helps if your URLs have semantics which are predictable and can be broken down easily.

Comment: If you tell us a bit more about your environment, there might be a specific answer that makes this easy, for instance, in django, it's usually sufficient to have `action="{{ request.path }}"` to get the same effect.

Answer (score 2):

I've always used (in PHP)

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); ?>">
```

To get my forms to submit to themselves.

Comment: As I already said: Use `htmlspecialchars()` and not `striptags()`!