# PHP - Self form submission: $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] OR action=""?

Tags: php, self, form-submit

I just realise that, for some weird circumstances, I was doing what I believe to be self submissions, without any reference to PHP_SELF on the action form attribute.

I'm puzzled, can we either use

```
<?php echo filter_var($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); ?>
```

Or

```
action=""
```

?

If not, on what circumstances should we considered one, or another?

Thanks in advance,
MEM

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use either (PHP_SELF or empty string). but why would you use FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING for this? You'd better to use [htmlentities()](http://php.net/htmlentities) instead of filter_var in this case, if your path contains filtered characters (e.g. `<`), the form won't submit.

I prefer giving a string, `<base href=>` can cause trouble when using empty values.
Example:

```
<form action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);?>" method="post">
</form>
```

Comment: Why one instead of another, can you please elaborate? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Characters like '<' in pathnames will be filtered, the resource won't be accessible.

Comment: this answer is missing `ENT_QUOTES`, at least. I don't really see the point - why not just use empty string? Escaping for all possible input tends to not be trivial, but using an empty string is.

Comment: @eis The empty string preserves query string parameters of the current page which may be unwanted. The default flags parameter contains `ENT_COMPAT` which converts double quotes. Only if you use single quotes for attributes, then you need `ENT_QUOTES`.

Comment: yes, which means that this answer will break for any single quotes, which I would consider unacceptable. query parameters of the url should relate to page being displayed, so I would consider more likely that they are needed than the case that they are not needed.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken Safari had/has problems with the latter, therefore I dropped using it.

Comment: @nikic - Thanks a lot.

@All - Can anyone else confirm if the above still applies? Or if it's a common case... I need more evidence to decide upon either to use it or not. :D

Comment: For more discussion on this, see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/415234/forms-with-action) and [this](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=19884). In short, the bug was resolved at 2009.

Answer (score -1):

Please do *not* use PHP_SELF, because this can also be `/index.php/"><script>alert(1)</script>/`.

It's often used for XSS Attacks.

Use the index **SCRIPT_NAME** instead! SCRIPT_NAME will always point to the actual PHP file and not to the user-input.

Regards

**Edit:**

Two people point out, that SCRIPT_NAME would not work when using mod_rewrite. This is false and I think these people should read before they vote answers down.

Here's a test scenario for you ***:

```
$ cat .htaccess 
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule testme/ /testmenot.php

$ cat testmenot.php 
<? echo $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']; ?>

$ GET hostname/testme/
/testmenot.php
```

`$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` is holding "/testme/", which i guess these people would have expected in SCRIPT_NAME. But that can also *not* be found in PHP_SELF.

*/me crosses fingers*
:E

Comment: -1, SCRIPT_NAME won't work for rewrited URL's. PHP_SELF can be used if you're checking it well.

Comment: @Jan: doesn't the filter_var or htmlentities deal with that?

Comment: `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']` does not work with rewritten URL:s. The XSS is not an issue if the receiving page redirects after parsing the request.

Comment: @Lekenstyn.. thanks for -1 but you're wrong: SCRIPT_NAME does actually work with rewritten URLs... it'll always point to the .php file and *not* to the given rewrite. When you want the QUERY_STRING you'll neither use SCRIPT_NAME nor PHP_SELF.

Comment: Jan, I've cases where resources are only accessible with the rewrited URL; requesting the file directly results gives a 404 page, without processing the request further. For various reasons, it's not prefferable to display the real file path directly.

Comment: @lekensteyn, that has nothing to do with you making false statements on a correct answer. It's merley an opinion regarding a project of yourself. But thanks for letting us know.

Comment: No Jan, your suggestion breaks about 80% of the standard frameworks I know of, not just Lekensteyn's pet project.  Having a single point of entry in for instance /index.php is quite common. You _are_ however right that XSS attacks should be avoided, but a simple `htmlspecialchars($var,ENT_QUOTES)` deals with that accordingly, or just whitelist urls & values and check those for more fine grained control.

Comment: You're correct in the way that most projects use a rewrite-name and it's then totally unwanted to use either PHP_SELF or SCRIPT_NAME. But that's still not the point here. On the other hand just using htmlentities may be enough from the security aspect, but it makes no sense to use anything random that a client sends as the target href of a form. This breaks unique content strategies and is not what one wants.

Answer (score -1):

```
     <?php
     session_start();
        $msg = '';

        if (isset($_POST['login']) && !empty($_POST['username']) 
           && !empty($_POST['password'])) {

           if ($_POST['username'] == 'abc' && 
              $_POST['password'] == 'xyz') {
              $_SESSION['valid'] = true;
              $_SESSION['timeout'] = time();
              $_SESSION['username'] = 'abc';
              ?>

              <script type="text/javascript">

          location.href="index.php"

        </script>
              <?php 
           }
           else 
           {
              $msg ='Invalid username or password';
           }
        }
     ?>
       <form
        action ="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); 
        ?>" method = "post">
              <input type = "text" class = "form-control" 
           name = "username" placeholder = "username" 
           required autofocus ></br> 
          <input type = "password" class = "form-control"
           name = "password" placeholder = "password" required>

      <input class="button" type = "submit"  name = "login" value="Log in"/>
```