# could not inserting data to mysql table using php

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

I have following form in html

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" />
                <fieldset>
                <legend>Activate Scheme</legend>
                <p>Date Of Draw</p>
                <p><input type="text" name="dateOfDraw" class="textBox" style="width:150px" /></p>

                <p>Time Of Draw</p>
                <p><input type="text" class="textBox" name="timeOfDraw" style="width:150px" /></p>

                <p>Enter scheme name</p>
                <p><input type="text" class="textBox" name="schemeName" style="width:150px" />
                </p>

                <p>Upload Image</p>
                <p><input type="file" name="image" id="image" /></p>

                <p><input name="scheme_button" type="submit" class="button1" value="Submit"></p>
                </fieldset>
        </form>
```

Problem is that their is no error when I execute the following query

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit_button']) && count($_POST)>0) {
    print_r($_POST);

    $dateOfDraw = $_POST['dateOfDraw'];
    $timeOfDraw = $_POST['timeOfDraw'];
    $schemeName = $_POST['schemeName'];
    $imageName = $_FILES['image']['name'];

    $destination = '../images/'.$imageName;
    $source = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
    if(move_uploaded_file($source, $destination)) {
        echo 'file uploaded';
    } else {
        echo ' file not uploaded';
    }

    $sSQL = "INSERT INTO landing_page(dateOfDraw, timeOfDraw, schemeName, image) VALUES('$dateOfDraw','$timeOfDraw','$schemeName','$imageName')";
    echo $sSQL;
    if(!$sSQL){
        die(mysqli_query($con));
        }
    mysqli_query($con,$sSQL);

    //header("location: list_products.php");
}
                ?>
```

but when I check my data in a mysql database the rows are still empty. Please check it am I missing something or the php code is wrong.
Note: I am using php version 5.5.16

Comment: what is wrong with it @JohnConde please point out me

Comment: Your code contains no SQL escaping, or error checking (mysqli_error). You could at least let on what `print_r` said.

Comment: @TinyCoder you connecting it to the database

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything.

Comment: @Utkarsh yes I am connecting it my all forms are working accept this

Comment: what is the name of your PHP file?

Comment: @mario actually print_r didn't say anything that is why I use it but it not working

Comment: Try my answer TinyCOder

Comment: @JohnRobertson index.php

Comment: see my answer put an action in your form action="index.php" make sure it's the PHP file that $_POST the values or the file that contains the same code above

Comment: @to all please vote me up for this question because I am new this coding so little mistakes could be possible thank you for your voting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of your submit button is `scheme_button` and that's exactly the thing that you need to `$_POST`.

```
 if(isset($_POST['scheme_button']) && count($_POST) > 0)
```

You form doesn't have an action and it doesn't know where to go. So add one.

```
<form method="post" action="index.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" />
```

Comment: I don't want any action I just want submit my form get stay on that page

Comment: @TinyCoder perhaps because you didn't clarify that or you can still add action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" to stay on the same page. However, this part is correct right? if(isset($_POST['scheme_button']) && count($_POST) > 0). Afterall, we're happy to help you

Comment: please don't angry I it's my mistake I check your answer late please don't mind. Please let me know if don't use action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" this then what are disadvantages.

Comment: @TinyCoder see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3620340/php-self-form-submission-serverphp-self-or-action. For additional learning. And this http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?439201-Difference-between-form-action-_SERVER-PHP_SELF-and-action-samefile-php

Answer (score 0):

firstly you have to name of submit button
 if(isset($_POST['scheme_button']) && count($_POST) > 0)

secondly if insert code in same page then

if insert code in another page then
action = "filename"