# What is the action attribute value for this scenario?

Tags: php, html, forms, action

I have a form at http://example.com/register/ . I want this form to be processed by the current page. How would that be done? Is it `action="../register/default.php"` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just do...

```
<form action="?"> ... </form>
```

...which will submit it to itself.

If you really wanted to use PHP, you could do that, too...

```
<form 
 action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); ?>">
    ...
</form>
```

This will echo the path after your domain that was used to access your page. It also includes GET params.

Comment: You could use `<form action="">` (empty) to submit to the current url (already include GET params)

Comment: @Bang Dao [They are not exactly the same](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/415234/forms-with-action).

Answer (score 0):

`<FORM name="form1" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" >`

Answer (score 0):

You can leave the action parameter blank to submit to the same page.

```
<form action="" method="post"></form>
```

Comment: [Apparently, that is problematic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/415234/forms-with-action).

Comment: The problem is that the issue did arise when `action=""` was specified.

Comment: Interesting. I frequently use this method and I've never had this problem with any of my testing or clients. I work with Safari, Chrome, Firefox, IE7-8 and sometimes Opera, so maybe the bug was fixed?