# Should I always set the "action" attribute?

Tags: php, html, forms

I've seen `<form>` opening tags that look like this:

```
<form action="<?= $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ?>">
```

Does the `action` attribute here make any sense?

Wouldn't the form behave the same way without it?

Comment: Why would you need a form then if not for redirecting to a page with information?

Comment: @OmerPT, you can have a form on a page, that detects if information was posted, then acts on it and sends a HTTP redirect header.

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/415234/forms-with-action

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should always include the `action` attribute in your form tag if you want a good valid markup (which you should). It is a required attribute (though most browsers will work around it if you don't and assume `action=""`).

Using:

```
<form action="" method="post">
```

...will work and just use the current page as the action page.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_form.asp

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you set it to blank you get the same effect (which is what I prefer)

```
<form action="" method="post"> ....
```

Comment: How about if you don't set it at all?

Comment: @Emanuil if you don't set it at all, it's the same as setting it to the file that contains that form

Comment: @Emanuil If you do not set it, you will have invalid HTML. And then most browsers will probably assume `action` attribute is empty (and will work as if they are supposed to send data to the current URL).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have to include `action` attribute within `<form>` tag. See some [documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.3).

However, you do not need to pass current URI, you can add empty `action` attribute like that:

```
<form action="">
...
</form>
```

and then the form will be sent to the current location (current URI).