# What does an entry "action='.'" in html form mean?

Tags: html, forms

I see this in my code with method post but can't figure out what exactly it does.

```
<form action="." method="POST" class="form-vertical">
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does an entry "action='?'" in html form mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17781842/what-does-an-entry-action-in-html-form-mean)

Comment: that's for "?" I'm looking for "."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`.` is the *current path segment* of the current URL. In other words, it refers to the current relative URL.

If your current URL is `http://example.com/foo/bar/baz/`, then `.` refers to `http://example.com/foo/bar/baz/` (yes, same URL).

It's a bit trickier without a trailing slash. On `http://example.com/foo/bar/baz`, `.` refers to `http://example.com/foo/bar/`. That's why it's not usually a good idea to use `.`; you could use `action=""` instead, which means `action` has an empty value, in which case the current (full) URL is substituted.

This `.` is pretty universal and is used in many contexts involving URLs or file paths.

Answer (score 0):

Action normally specifies the file/page that the form is submitted to using the method described in the method parameter post or get.

. (dot) is the current path.
you can try a demo here 
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_form_submit

try to upload your form using 
action="." or action="" or action="/"

you will see the difference