# Cannot send form using POST

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

Recently new installation of laravel.
Trying to send a minimal basic form using POST. Get errors as below.
Try below scenarios, but none of them result in successfully processing the form.

**My form**

```
 <form method="post" action="/form_populating_data">

   @csrf_field
   {{ method_field('PUT') }}

  <?php foreach ($array as $key => $value): ?>

    <label
    for= <?php echo "'{$key}'" ?>
    >
    <?php echo "{$key}" ?>
    </label>

    <input
    type="text"
    id="1"
    value= <?php echo "{$value}" ?>
    >

    <br>

  <?php endforeach; ?>


  <input type="submit" name="" value="Save">

</form>
```

---

**Troubleshooting tests**

**Startpoint, keep "get" [routes/web.php]**

```
Route::get('/form_populating_data', function () {
    return view('site_tax_declarations/form_populating_data');
});
```

Result:

```
The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD.
```

---

**Adjust, change to "post" [routes/web.php]**

```
Route::post('/form_populating_data', function () {
    return view('site_tax_declarations/form_populating_data');
});
```

Result:

```
The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.
```

---

**Adjust [form.php], keep [Route:get]**

Added following between POST tags:

```
@csrf_field
{{ method_field('PUT') }}
```

Result:

The PUT method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD.

---

**Adjust [form.php], Change to [Route:post]**

Added following between POST tags:

```
@csrf_field
{{ method_field('PUT') }}
```

Result:

The PUT method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.

---

**Adjust [form.php], keep [Route:get]**
Updated with action="/form_populating_data"

Removed:

```
@csrf_field
{{ method_field('PUT') }}
```

Result:

```
The PUT method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD.
```

Comment: Add the form code

Comment: Maybe you need to add the `action` attribute? is the request being sent to the right place?

Comment: @jewishmoses As a start I just want to run the post, no need of action, it is enough that I would see the result through var_dump($_POST). Updated the question.

Comment: I don't think we are on the same page. [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17781842/what-does-an-entry-action-in-html-form-mean)

Comment: you need to add action to tell the form which url will be used:
<form method="post" action="/form_populating_data">

Comment: @jewishmoses Outside Laravel you can submit a POST form without action and get the POST result visible through var_dump($_POST). I only use attribute action, to move the logics into separate file, of course the result would also be that that the main page of form is not visible since the form page moves to the defined action page. Is it different in Laravel?

Comment: You need to update the route from `Route::get("/process-data"...` to `Route::post("/process-data"...`

Comment: Can you show your full `routes.php` file rather? share it here kopy.io

Comment: `@csrf`  should be 
`{{ csrf_field() }}` not `@csrf_field` change it to just `@csrf`

Answer (score 1):

I think there's a misunderstanding in how Http Request work.
You need one route to deliver the form to the user:

```
Route::get('/form_populating_data', function () {
    return view('site_tax_declarations/form_populating_data');
});
```

In your form you use a route for processing the data like `<form action="/process-data' method="post">`.

Then you need a post route with this endpoint:

```
Route::post("/process-data", function (Request $request) {
  dd($request->input());
});
```

Note: Injecting the `Request` in the route handler.

The POST input then is available in `$request->input()`.

**EDIT: Your form fields need the `name` attribute like `<input name="message">`. Then the values are available with `$request->input("message")`**

Additional info you can find in the routing documentation:

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/routing

Answer (score -2):

you should do it in this way

```
  {{ method_field('PUT') }}
  @csrf_field
```

If you are using PUT Method for updation then you should write it before the csrf field. Method spoofing should be written before csrf.

Hope it will work now.

Comment: This is wrong! It doesn't matter at all because both are simply hidden fields that are submitted with the request.