# How does the "action" attribute work in a Django form?

Tags: python, html, django

I have learned about forms in Django(from scratch and using ModelForm). ModelForm is super helpful!

I can code the whole thing, but one thing that got me confused is the "action=" attribute in a form tag on a template.

Here is my confusion. I use the 'method' attribute, but I have seen people use the action='/example_path/'. What does that mean and how does it work in Django? Is it ok to just use the "method=post" attribute?

drinks_form.html :

```
    {% extends 'robots/base.html' %}
    {% load static %}

    {% block content %}

        <h3 class="main-title">Let us know your opinion of a drink of choice: 
        </h3>

        <form method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.as_p }}
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>

    {% endblock %}
```

I fill in the form, click the submit button, and the 'thanks page' appears, everythin Ok.

It appears to working fine, instances are being created and saved in my 'Drinks' table. I go into python shell and list all the objects created from my Drinks class and they are there.

Also, I include the table in my admin site and they get saved no problem.

What does the 'action' attribute do specifically? I know this might be an noob HTML question but I just started coding 6 months ago, so bear with me!

```
     <form action='' method='post'>
     #...
     </form>
```

Thanks everyone. Hope my question was clear.

Comment: Posting all of your code has made it hard to understand what you're asing about, you need to make a [mcve]

Comment: will do, my bad.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/17781842/1324033

it tells your form where to send its data

Answer (score 1):

The `action` is basic HTML stuff (see: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_action.asp).
It defines to what URL will the browser POST or GET (depending on the method) the filled form. Now, if the value is empty it will use the same URL that is in the browser location bar at the moment.

In Django terms leaving the action empty, it will POST the data to the same URL and thus, usually, the same view. Thus you have to check in the view if there is stuff in `request.POST` or `request.GET` to know if the user was loading the view for the first time or posting the form. For example, UpdateView (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/) will do this automatically.

A good habit is to redirect the user after a successful POST so that a page reload does not post the form again.

Comment: So basically, "action" is just rendering or redirecting the user to a new html template, thus showing a new page on the screen? In my view, after the data validation part, I use "Httpresponseredirect('/thanks-message/')", which is the path of the html template I want the user to see rendered on the screen after the submit button is clicked. Sorry for my ignorance but couldnt find info on that on the django docs. I will be checking out your links provided, thanks.

Comment: @Tom i am also confused about that some people say action sends the data to the url which is given to action, but why we send data to url?

Comment: @Tariq in HTTP we make requests to the web server. You can include data in the request but also define the request method (GET/POST/PUT...). For every request you have to tell the endpoint so that the web server knows what you try to achieve and serve the request with the right response. Now, in POST request you can give a body that the web server then interprets. But you still have to tell the web server what you want it to do with the correct url.