# HTML , action = ''', irregular response to form submit

Tags: html, forms

I have a form on page www.mysite.com/myPage.php that mosttimes works but occasionally sends the form to the index page.

This is because I-m using the html 4.x style  < action "">.

So what is the best generic option (not specifying the page url) to keep the form to the same page? Html would be cleaner than php, no?

The following question is 3 years old and has no accepted answer ([Forms with action=""](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415234/forms-with-action))

Comment: Action=""?, In the action attribute of your form put ./myPage.php

Comment: blank action"" should redirect to same page

Comment: @Gamemorize A blank `action=""` attribute leaves it down to the browser implementation. Defining it as the current page is better (See [W3 Bug Tracker](https://www.w3.org/Bugs/Public/show_bug.cgi?id=14215#c1))

Comment: possible duplicate of [Forms with action=""](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/415234/forms-with-action)

Comment: OK, I see that action "" is not the done thing anymore... I-ll accept an answer that replaces it with the latest cross/browser GENERIC mode to have action direct to same page..