# HTML - Empty form with one button doesn't submit the form

Tags: html

```
<form action="?action=paste&path=<?=$path?>">
    <input type="submit" value="Paste">
</form>
```

I'm moved to / with no any parameters when click the button. What's wrong?

Comment: I have answered below. Please, if that do not work, would you tell us if there is something displayed in console?

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do with `<?=$path?>` ? That is not HTML. If it is intended to be php, it should be `<?php echo $path; ?>` or `<? echo $path; ?>`.

Also, what is the file that should handle the request? You should specify it like this: `<form action="form-handler.php?param1=value1&param2=value2">`. If the form should be submitted to the same page, then replace `form-handler` with the name of your page file.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415234/forms-with-action) you can find why you have to specify the action handler.

Also, I guess you are missing the `method` attribute in your form element.