# Most secure value for action attribute in the <form> tag

Tags: php, html, forms

I wanted to know what is the most secure option for the action attribute as many people says `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` is not secure. Is it fine to give empty string for action attribute? But the output is different for `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` and empty string.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14093316/why-use-serverphp-self-instead-of .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why use $\_SERVER\['PHP\_SELF'\] instead of ""](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14093316/why-use-serverphp-self-instead-of)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there really is a truly "secure" way of populating the action attribute of a form. For example, I can open web console and modify the form anyway I want to.

That said, I think the real concern you are getting at is if someone were to send a link where an exploit designed to change the value of PHP_SELF has been used. The person who gets the link has no way of knowing that the form has been compromised.

So, I generally like to hard-code my action URL's where I can. If they must be dynamic, you can validate them against a list of URL's that you would expect to make sure it makes sense.

There is also nothing wrong with an empty action attribute, but you might take a look at [Forms with action=""](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415234/forms-with-action)

Edit: To sum up my original post:
I think Hard-coded URL's are the best.
A "#" or an empty string would be next (effectively, it is still a hard-coded URL).
I try to avoid PHP_SELF where ever possible, and validate it against known, legitimate URL's when I have to use it.

Comment: Hi Jason thanks for your answer. I just wanted to know which one is comparatively better? an empty string or # or PHP_SELF?

Comment: I guess my answer was a bit vague. I prefer an empty string, since it helps prevent phishing and other unexpected behavior.